# Apply Lighting to specific checkboxes in gl_Quad

Tags: c++, opengl

I want to apply different lighting on white and black boxes in this checkerboard.So far what I've done.

The nested loop in the myDisplay function is creating the boxes.

```
GLfloat ambientColor[] = {0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f}; //Color(0.2, 0.2, 0.2)
GLfloat lightColor0[] = {0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f}; //Color (0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
GLfloat lightPos0[] = {4.0f, 0.0f, 8.0f, 1.0f}; //Positioned at (4, 0, 8)
GLfloat lightColor1[] = {0.5f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f}; //Color (0.5, 0.2, 0.2)
//Coming from the direction (-1, 0.5, 0.5)
GLfloat lightPos1[] = {-1.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f};
void myInit(void)
{
glClearColor (1,1,0,0);
glPointSize(10);
glLineWidth(10.0);
glColor3f(1,1,1);
gluOrtho2D(0,640,0,480); 
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
//gluPerspective(45,2,-2,2);
gluLookAt(100.0,200.0,200.0,//eyeposition
    0.0,0.0,0.0,//ccenter
    0.0,1.0,0.0);//up direction 
}
void myDisplay(void)
{
int posx=10;
int posy=10;
int posWidth=60;
int posHeight=60;
bool whiteORBlack=true;

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);


 // glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_DIFFUSE, lightColor1);
 // glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_POSITION, lightPos1);
for(int j=1;j<=8;j++)
{
    for(int i=1;i<=8;i++)
    {
        if(whiteORBlack==true)
        {
            glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            glColor3f(0,0,0);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, lightColor0);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, lightPos0);

glLightModelfv(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT, ambientColor);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, lightColor0);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, lightPos0);

            glVertex2i(posx,posy);
            glVertex2i(posx+posWidth,posy);
            glVertex2i(posx+posWidth,posy+posHeight);
            glVertex2i(posx,posy+posHeight);
            whiteORBlack=false;

        }
        else if(whiteORBlack==false)
        {
            glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            glColor3f(1,1,1);

            glVertex2i(posx,posy);
            glVertex2i(posx+posWidth,posy);
            glVertex2i(posx+posWidth,posy+posHeight);
            glVertex2i(posx,posy+posHeight);
            whiteORBlack=true;
        }
            posx=posx+posWidth;
    }

    if(whiteORBlack==false)
    {
        whiteORBlack=true;
    }
    else
    {
        whiteORBlack=false;
    }
    posy=posy+posHeight;

    posx=10;
}


//glPopMatrix();
//glutSwapBuffers();
glEnd();
glFlush();
 }
  void main(int argc,char ** argv)
 {
glutInit(&argc,argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE|GLUT_RGB);
glutInitWindowSize (640,480);
glutInitWindowPosition(100,150);
glutCreateWindow("FINAL LAB");
myInit();
glutDisplayFunc(myDisplay);
//glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
//glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
//glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0,GL_AMBIENT,light0_ambient);
//glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0,GL_DIFFUSE,ligth0_diffuse);
//glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
//glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
//glEnable(GL_BLEND);
//glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
//glLineWidth(2);
//glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
/*gluPerspective(40,1,1,10);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
gluLookAt(0.0,0.0,5.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0);*/
glutMainLoop();
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you'd have to set all of your `glLightfv` stuff to `lightColor1` etc.

Instead of swapping this around every time, I'd probably set the lighting for black, draw all of the black ones, and then set the lighting for white, and draw all of the white ones.

If I'm wrong, then a screenshot may help up answer you better.